# Fluent Design Toolkit for WPF

Tags: wpf, uwp, fluent, toolkit

Microsoft announced in May 2018 that they would soon be publishing the Fluent Design Toolkit for WPF.
Is there already more information when it will be published?

Comment: You can check out this links if helpful https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2018/10/10/fluent-xaml-theme-editor-preview-released/

Comment: Thank you!
But does this toolkit only work for UWP apps or can it also be used in WPF?

Comment: I think same should be working for WPF as ITs just XAML

Comment: I have installed the NuGet package Microsoft.UI.Xaml. Unfortunately it does not work with WPF. I got an exception that the expression [System.Version] :: Parse ("") can not be evaluated. Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your existing WPF or Windows applications with Fluent Design features. You need to see [Host UWP controls in WPF and Windows Forms applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/xaml-host-controls#host-controls). You could use UWP features and controls that support the Fluent Design System in your existing WPF, Windows Forms, and C++ Win32 applications. This developer scenario is sometimes called XAML islands.

> **Please note that** XAML islands are currently available as a developer preview. Although we encourage you to try them out in your own prototype code now, we do not recommend that you use them in production code at this time. These APIs and controls will continue to mature and stabilize in future Windows releases. Microsoft makes no warranties, express or implied, with respect to the information provided here.
>
> If you have feedback about XAML islands, create a new issue in the WindowsCommunityToolkit repo and leave your comments there. If you prefer to submit your feedback privately, you can send it to XamlIslandsFeedback@microsoft.com. Your insights and scenarios are critically important to us.

To use UWP XAML hosting APIs, you also need to check if you meet the [prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/using-the-xaml-hosting-api#prerequisites).

Answer (score 0):

Those projects mimic the FluentUI style on WPF:

- [MahApps.Metro](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro)

  - It's baked into the WPF project template of [Windows Template Studio for VS2022](https://github.com/microsoft/TemplateStudio).
  - However, the style is stuck at Metro / Win8.
  - Pretty large user base.
- [WPF-UI](https://github.com/lepoco/wpfui)

  - [first found it on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/csharp/comments/uiccv1/fluent_ui_in_windows_presentation_foundation_wpf/)
  - Windows 11 style
  - tiny user base :(
- [ModernWpf](https://github.com/Kinnara/ModernWpf)

  - Takes use of MahApps
  - Unsure what's the benefit of using `ModernWpf` over `MahApps`
  - [Pull request to apply Windows 11 style](https://github.com/Kinnara/ModernWpf/pull/446=)